# Sales Order Export CSV in Magento2

Tags: csv, magento2.1

How can we add new column with custom data in the “Order Export CSV” like  discount amount, coupon code, Product Attributes?

Comment: what class method is called when the "Export" button is clicked?
The button has this attribute onclick="applyOption;", but I am not able to figrure out what php file is called ultimatley.
data-bind="click: applyOption, i18n: 'Export'"
Can you please help me out?

Comment: after that it calls the  below controller :
/admin/mui/export/gridToCsv/
URL is :
http://localhost/magento217/admin/mui/export/gridToCsv/key/?filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&search=&namespace=sales_order_grid&selected%5B%5D=3&selected%5B%5D=2

I found the code under the controller is :
public function execute()
{
return $this->fileFactory->create('export.csv', $this->converter->getCsvFile(), 'var');
}
Now I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by myself spend few hours on it. Below steps will clear solution.

1) Create New Column in below xml

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

<column name="custom_product_name" class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Price">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Product Name</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

2) alter sales_order_grid table, (Using upgrade Schema)

```
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_grid` ADD `custom_product_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ;
```

Note: column name of table and column name in XML should be same.

3) Run Observer after the place order. [StackOverflow - Which observer to use after success order on Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162635/which-observer-to-use-after-success-order-on-magento-2/162648)

**Important : DO NOT work in core files, you have to override all the files in your module.**